# When you kill someone, do you get his hat?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I don't know if it's just my own misinformation, but I've always believed that if you kill an enemy wearing a hat, you have a higher chance of receiving his hat in the next drop. Does this have a ring of truth to it, or am I just full of baloney?

Comment: No, this is a folk legend. There isn't any such mechanic in the item drop system.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may be thinking of the [Ghastly Gibus](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Ghastly_Gibus)- a Halloween themed top hat. This hat is given to a player when they dominate another player wearing a Gibus. The [Pyrovision Goggles](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Pyrovision_Goggles) do the same thing.

The drop rates of other hats are not affected by who you kill.